# Why fresh installed Windows 10 VM generates 4624/4625 whereas Audit account logon events is set to "No auditing" in Audit Policy

Tags: windows

All is in the title.
By the way, each policies are set to "No auditing" in Audit Policy by default but we still get events in the Event Viewer.
I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured legacy audit policies.  Those are not used by default. The audit policies are configured under Windows Settings\Security Settings\Advanced Audit Policy configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did not configure anything. I just installed a Win10 VM and realized that a lot of events are enabled by default and it does not match what I see in the Audit Policy.

If I open "Local Security Policy" and go to "Security Settings \ Advanced Audit Policy\System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object\Logon/Logoff", I get all subcategory to "Not Configured"

Comment: But in the "Explain" tab from "Properties" its says "Default on Client editions: Success."

So maybe that means that if you do not configure anything, it put this value by default. It would explain 4624 but not 4625 :/

Comment: If `auditpol /get /category:*` shows it enabled, it would need to be configured in the policy to change it.

Comment: I executed your command. I got "No Auditing" for all "Logon/Logoff" category

Comment: Oops now I don't get any 462[4|5] anymore. Maybe I've changed something during my manipulations. Thank you for your clarifications though.